# TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: callable

I can't figure out how to fix the errors I keep receiving, I have them at the bottom of the code below.

```
 import random
```

## this function creates a random number file

```
def random_number_file_create(min, max, filenames, entries):
    random_number_file  = open(FILENAME, "w")
    for i in range (entries):
            number = str(random.randint(min, max))
            random_number_file.write(number + "\n")
    random_number_file.close()
```

## this function prints the random number

```
def lines_print(filename):
    random_number_file = open(FILENAME, "r")
    line = random_number_file.readline()
    while line != "":
            print(line, end="")
            line = random_number_file()
    random_number_file.close()
```

## this function counts the lines containing random number

```
def lines_count(filename):
    random_number_file = open (FILENAME, "r")
    line = random_number_file.readline()
    count = 0
    for number in random_number_file:
            count += 1
    return count
    random_number_file.close()
```

## this function adds the total of the numbers

```
def total_numbers_in_file(filename):
    random_number_file = open (FILENAME, "r")
    line = random_number_file.readline()
    total=0
    for number in random_number_file:
            total = int(number)
    return total
    random_number_file.close()
FILENAME= "numbers.txt"
random.seed(83)
random_number_file_create(50,100,FILENAME,20)
lines_print(FILENAME)
print()
entries = lines_count(FILENAME)
total = total_numbers_in_file(FILENAME)
average = round(total/entries)
print("Entries:", entries)
print("Total:", total)
print("Average:", average)
```

#Errors#
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hw8.py", line 41, in 
        lines_print(FILENAME)
      File "hw8.py", line 18, in lines_print
        line = random_number_file()
    TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Answer (score -1):

Providing a reference case:

Another similar case, the error tip is :

`Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "ex17.py", line 18, in <module>
        input<'?'>
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable.`

the asker support his code, and another Technology Daniel find that
he use 'input' as a variable, but then in the following lines, he also use the 'input' function to get a data from  the users. That's the real reason.

when i run my module, the system show me a same error as you, but my error is the same as the pevious asker. So by changing the 'input' variable as a different variabe 'input_1', i solve the error.

I hope my answer could help you, actually i am new to python, i can read your code and understand, but i can't find the truth.